# pandas plot displays wrong months from datetime on x-axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot stacked bar chart using pandas and matplotlib. I want months to be located on x-axis from datetimes. But It always shows "jan", despite the month given.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'value1':[1,2], 'value2':[5,4]},
                   index=[datetime(year=2020, month=3, day=3),
                          datetime(year=2020, month=4, day=6)])
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
```

How to change the code so that it displays correct month on x-axis?

I tried to also display year and day for debugging purposes, and it gives 'Jan 01 1970' for the first bar and 'Jan 02 1970' for the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) the *DatetimeIndex* as (`"%b"`) ?

```
df.index = df.index.strftime('%b') # <-- add this line and remove the mdates formatter

ax = df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True) # or `df.plot.bar(stacked=True)`

plt.show();
```

Ouptut :

[image]